# Sign in web application after aproval with Pincode

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I was wondering how authentication work with some apps on my iphone. When I understand this method I want to implement it within my own application. Some Apps ask after registration to create a pincode and you can always login with that pincode again (Mobile Banking Apps). Now I use JWT authentication, but it expires after 24 hours, and people need to fill in their credentials again. I'm reading all over the internet that you can't store credentials on the user his device (obviously). So i'm looking for other method, or maybe merge other methods?

The idea of those PIN-protected apps: The First time you need to login these apps, you can authenticate with a password/number which is shown on a secondary device (Like 2 factor authentication). When authentication is proven, you'll be asked to create a pincode. At this moment I was thinking about storing the deviceId inside my database, and store the associated pin number with it. Cause i'm 100% sure that the user from that device is the user who asks for authentication.

Unfortunatelty as I understand, it is impossible to get Apple's deviceId. SO i was thinking further... Maybe I can store a unique token on the device after authentication, store this unique token in my database, and add pin number to it? But where do I store that unique token on the mobile device?

I'm trying to find out how these apps work.

Thanks in advance for reading my question.

Regards, Ron

Comment: Why can't you store the credentials In the user device?   Personally, I would much prefer you save the pin code in the secure keychain of my iOS device and use TouchID control access to it than on your server.

Comment: And how would you advice on Android Devices? From my understanding it is possible for other apps to read the internal storage of the device. So technically they would be able to retreive the stored username and password from localStorage. I understand that IOS keychain is safe

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Android.  I just assume Android users aren't worried about security, that is why they chose that platform  

Comment: ahaha I think I agree with you. But I would like to provide as much as security as possible. Is there a unique deviceID I can verify and store in my database? So i'm sure which devices is used next time to log in?